# Forward to Viber with both number and text

Tags: android, android-intent, viber

does anybody know how to forward a text from my application to a specified number in Viber? Is it possible?

I have tried these two ways:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);         
             sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:00000000000"));
             sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "text"); 
             startActivity(sendIntent);
```

This one is forwarding to desired number correctly, but not passes the text.

and

```
            String S1="test message";
            Uri sms_uri = Uri.parse("smsto:00000000000"); 
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND, sms_uri);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, S1);
            //sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, "00000000000");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share using"));
```

The above code is forwarding the text to viber but needs to select a number or contact to send the text.
I have tried almost any combinations of these two methods but could not achieve the goal.

I'm stuck with this for months, Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is first method works for you? its not works for me! it just open viber`s main activity :(

Comment: @MostafaLavaei Nope! Unfortunately i couldn't find a way to do the job!

Comment: But i see this feature in other apps, it means its possible.
Please notify me if you find any solution. ThanX.